# Eclipse shows multiple errors in Physics Box2D extension

Tags: java, android, eclipse, andengine

I am following a tutorial and developing an Android game using AndEngine and Physics Box2D Extension. In a while I found out that there was a problem with (eclipse or) Physics Box2D Extension. Eclipse shows multiple errors in following

Package: `org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d`

Classes:

- `FixedStepPhysicsWorld.java`
- `PhysicsConnector.java`
- `PhysicsConnectorManager.java`
- `PhysicsFactory.java`
- `PhysicsWorld.java`

Example errors:

> The hierarchy of the type FixedStepPhysicsWorld is inconsistent, The import org.andengine.engine cannot be resolved

Package: `org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util`

Class: `Vector2Pool.java`

Example errors:

> The import org.andengine.util cannot be resolved, GenericPool cannot be resolved to a type

I tried to post some screenshots to make the case more clear but I can't. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A tip with images: Upload it on any image host e.g [image shack](http://imageshack.us/), then any user with enough reputation will add it to your post.

Comment: Thanks mate. So any tip on the other problem?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't know Java.

Comment: Did you download the code from github? If so, are you using compatible branches (for example, all GLES 2)?

Comment: I got the AndEngine from [link]https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine and the Extension from [link]https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension

It should work right? But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had these error a lot of times.

1. you should check that you use same andengine version for the extension(GLES1.0,GLES 2.0 or GLES 2.0 AC).
   2.If you do have same version, delete all of them from eclipse and try to import them back and than clean them.

Hope it works.

Comment: I got the AndEngine from https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine and the Extension from https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension It should work right? But it doesn't

Comment: Tried deleting AndEngine and the Extension from the directory and importing them again and cleaning the projects. Still the same issue

Comment: It was a stupid mistake in my part. AndEngine wasn't imported correctly to the extension. It works fine now. Thanks